# Type 'Observable<Observable<Response>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Response>'

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular10

Using Angular 10 I have the following method:

```
private getUser() : Observable<Response> {

  return this.authenticationService.getClaims('sub').pipe(map((claims: Claim[]) => {

    let request: Request = { userId: 1 };

    return this.userService.getByUserId(request).pipe(
      map((payload: Payload<Response[]>) => payload.result[0])
    );

  }));

}
```

I am getting the error:

```
Type 'Observable<Observable<Response>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Response>'.
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating an inner Observable requires flattening, which could be achieved using [SwitchMap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap)/[MergeMap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/mergeMap) operator, as demonstrated below:

```
private getUser() : Observable < Response > {

  return this.authenticationService.getClaims('sub').pipe(
    switchMap((claims: Claim[]) => {

      let request: Request = { userId: 1 };

      return this.userService.getByUserId(request).pipe(
        map((payload: Payload<Response[]>) => payload.result[0])
      );

    }));

}
```

Here's a great article about [Understanding RxJS map, mergeMap, switchMap and concatMap](https://medium.com/@luukgruijs/understanding-rxjs-map-mergemap-switchmap-and-concatmap-833fc1fb09ff)